# How do I enforce the length of an array in variable declaration (CS0270)?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, methods, language-design

Why C#'s design doesn't allow declarations like these?

```
public int[10] someInts;
public int[10] someMethod();
```

These lines throw the CS0270 error. What is the reason behind that? The ability to enforce array's length in an interface or for overriding classes would be useful in some situations.

**EDIT:**

Following Marc Gravell's comment, what I want to point out is the fact that the array's length is known when it gets created just as its type. If we can enforce array's type when assigning it to a field/returned value, why we can't enforce its length? It would make the code like this fail:

```
int length = 10;
int[] arr = new int[length];
int[10] anotherArr = arr; //length not known at compile time
```

the same way as this one does:

```
string obj1 = "";
object obj2 = "";
obj1 = obj2; //cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'
```

Comment: `why we can't enforce its length` Because the compiler doesn't do that - no-one built that feature in. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/ shows the kind of thinking you need to take into account when adding 'easy features' (and this is definitely **not** an easy feature).

Answer (score 4):

An array's length is determined when you *create* it; you aren't creating any arrays there, so you can't determine the length. You cannot define the length of an array in a field signature, or in the return part of a method signature.

- the field just holds a reference to an array: what length it is is up to whatever code *creates the array* and assigns it the the field
- the method just returns an array: what length it is is up to whatever code *creates the array* and returns it

The only time a length is part of a *declaration* is for "fixed buffers", but: that isn't an array (it is *somewhat array-like*, but: not an array; it is also an advanced topic that most people should never need to use).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is it really impossible to make these declarations impossible? The array's length is known when it gets created just like its type (both are fixed too), so why we can't check it when assigning/returning it from the method (of course it would make it impossible to assign any array which has length unknown at compile time to a field like this, even if the length was right)?

Comment: @anuar2k it is known when created *if* it is a trivial scenario. Most aren't. You could, however, do something like wrap the array in a class that exposes the value via an indexer and always allocates a fixed size array. Or, you could do the same thing with a structured and a "fixed buffer"

Answer (score 1):

While C# does not have this feature, the intermediate code that C# (and other .NET langauges) compile into - Common Intermediate Language (CIL, also known as IL or MSIL) - **does** allow you to specify the dimensions of an array as part of the type. From [the relevant ECMA spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), section I.8.9.1:

> An array type shall be defined by specifying the element type of the array, the rank (number of dimensions) of the array, and the upper and lower bounds of each dimension of the array. [...] While the actual bounds for each dimension are known only at runtime, the signature can specify the information that is known at compile time (e.g., no bounds, a lower
>   bound, or both an upper and a lower bound).

In CIL, you can declare arrays that fit C#'s definition, with a lower bound of 0 and an unspecified upper bound, e.g. `int32[]`. You can also specify an explicit upper bound, e.g. `int32[0...5]`.

You could use a tool that works with CIL - such as [the ILSupport Visual Studio extension](https://github.com/ins0mniaque/ILSupport) - to define arrays with explicit upper bounds as fields, arguments, etc. But I can't speak to how well other code, written in C#, would work with it.